# Always focus timelinesetter card on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use [TimelineSetter Plugin](http://propublica.github.com/timeline-setter/) from [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/propublica/timeline-setter).

The problem is that when a TS-item is bigger than the half of the Timeline the plugin does not know where to put the activate card thus it is hidden because it is getting outside of the timeline. The good thing is that when you zoom and the size of the Card(TS-item) is less than half the size of the timeline everything works ok.

An example of the above problem is illustrated in this jsFiddle repository:

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Vpz2U/4/)

[image]

I tried to fixed the problem and I made the size of the card the same size of the timeline and when the cards are moved I do not move the card but the arrow of the card. Unfortunately, This introduces other problems with the `Zoom` functionality.

[Working demo: Problem with Zoom](http://jsfiddle.net/Vpz2U/10/)

Can someone point me to the right direction on how I can fix this?

Comment: It looks like the example for the plugin works correctly (and it looks like you've based the fiddle on it) http://propublica.github.com/timeline-setter/doc/twitter-demo.html
Could this be a problem with your browser?  I'm using Chrome

Comment: the example works correctly because the width of the card that is changing is less than half the size of the timeline. But check my example with a bigger card. it gets outside of the timeline!

Comment: Ah forgive me, I didn't experiment with it enough.  I did resize my browser window to try it out but I didn't click any examples that failed.  A lot still work, but some fail.

Comment: It looks like you'll have to make a change to the `flip` function in the source.  Search for `flip : function() {` in that fiddle and you'll see it.  You might also have to look at `move` (search for `move : function() {`)

Answer (score 1):

I didnt look at the code to much, but it seems to me that the problem is that the card gets to much of a "left:" css property.

Try taking out the left: and just moving the yellow arrow that points to the timeline section.